# lag scrolling scrollview with tableview inside it

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll, scrollview

I have important problem with `UIScrollView`.

I want to make one app like yahoo weather and using this source code : [BTGlassScrollView](https://github.com/jspooner/BTGlassScrollView)

in this source code exist one view with name "foregroundView" that is info view. this info view appear when scrolling my `ScrollView` from bottom to top.
now I make and add my `ScrollView` by this code:

```
_viewScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width + 2*blackSideBarWidth, self.view.frame.size.height)];
 [_viewScroller setPagingEnabled:YES];
 [_viewScroller setDelegate:self];
 [_viewScroller setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
 [self.view addSubview:_viewScroller];

 _glassScrollView1 = [[BTGlassScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame BackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background3"] blurredImage:nil viewDistanceFromBottom:0 foregroundView:[self customView]];
 [_viewScroller addSubview:_glassScrollView1];
```

in my code I write `[self customView]` that make me info view and this is **customView** function:

```
- (UIView *)customView {
    //this method is for make UITableView
    [self makeTableBuy:[[self.tableDic objectForKey:@"person"] count]];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _tableBuy.frame.size.width, _tableBuy.frame.size.height)];
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.3];
    [view addSubview:_tableBuy];
    return view;
}

- (UITableView*)makeTableBuy:(int)numberOfRow {

    _tableBuy  = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,numberOfRow*TABLE_HEIGHT) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [_tableBuy setTag:1];
    [_tableBuy setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    _tableBuy.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _tableBuy.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    _tableBuy.rowHeight = TABLE_HEIGHT;
    _tableBuy.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _tableBuy.delegate = self;
    _tableBuy.dataSource = self;
    return _tableBuy;
}
```

now When I'm scrolling my `ScrollView` my info view (my tableview) moving to top and appear but my scrolling have so lagging.

please guide me how to fix this **lag**???